# How can I have the title of a webpage change when it is refreshed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, title

I was wondering if there is a simple way of having the title of a webpage change between some chosen presets stored as a list somewhere each time the page is loaded/refreshed?

For example [Wowhead](http://www.wowhead.com/) where the title changes each time the page is loaded.

I've been looking for a while but can't find any tutorials or anything about it. Any help at all would be helpful.

EDIT: Thanks for your help you guys. I'm not very good at this kind of stuff but I eventually managed to get it to work after using some of your advice to keep searching.

I eventually got it going with:

```
public string randomTitle()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    var page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
    int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 10);
    string response;
    switch (randomNumber)
    {
        case 0:
            response = "someTitle0";
            break;
        case 1:
            response = "someTitle1";
            break;
        case 2:
            response = "someTitle2";
            break;
        //I had more in here but you get the picture
    }
    return response;
}
```

and on the page I called it with:

```
  <title><%=randomTitle()%></title>
```

Thanks for all of your help everyone who responded. I probably wouldn't have been able to do it if you hadn't (I did spend a good while searching before asking, I just didn't know what to search.)

Comment: Do you want to change the title dynamically?

Comment: I would approach this using server-side functionality instead of JavaScript

Comment: `document.title = "Hello World!";` now all you have to do is randomize "Hello World!" I would do this with javascript first to see if search engines ignore it that way i can serve the seo friendly title with the server, then change it with js after.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked http://www.wowhead.com/ and found that everytime when page refreshed it just randomly updated the page title.Below example used javascript to set page title.I suggest to use server side script for the same.

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>


$(document).ready(function(){

var randomno=Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
var pagetitle='This is Page Title';
if(randomno==1)
{   
    pagetitle='Title-1';
}
else if(randomno==3)
{
    pagetitle='Title-3';
}
else if(randomno==5)
{
    pagetitle='Title-5';
}
else if(randomno==2)
{
    pagetitle='Title-2';
}
else if(randomno==7)
{
    pagetitle='Title-7';
}
else
{
pagetitle='Default page title';
}
$(document).attr('title', pagetitle);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```